How to Check if an Object is Serializable at Compile-time or Runtime Using json_serializable in Flutter?
I have a question regarding the json_serializable package for Flutter.

Is there any way to check at compile-time if an object is serializable using json_serializable?
If not, is there a way to check at runtime if an object is serializable without using reflection?

To provide more context, I want to achieve something similar to checking if a class inherits from another class. However, since json_serializable works with decorators instead of inheritance, I don't see a clear way to perform this check.
Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'example.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Person {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person({required this.name, required this.age});

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}

void main() {
  var person = Person(name: 'John', age: 30);

  // This should compile only if T is serializable
  processSerializable(person);
}

// Pseudocode for the generic method I'm trying to implement
void processSerializable<*T extends ...?*>(T object) {
  // The implementation should ensure at compile-time that T is serializable
  if (isSerializable<T>()) {
    print('The object is serializable');
  } else {
    print('The object is not serializable');
  }
}

// How can I implement isSerializable function to perform compile-time check?

Any guidance on how to implement the isSerializable function to ensure compile-time checks or any alternative approach to ensure that T is serializable would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

You have to use Reflection to inspect the annotations to see if @JsonSerializable is present. You cannot do this at compile time.

check the upcoming macro : https://dart.dev/language/macros#trigger-custom-diagnostics

@SayyidJ finally something that should be done long ago! awesome

Not sure if it is useful for your purpose, but this could be easily done for classes that you control, like Person.
Just define an interface:
abstract interface class Serializable {

  /// Converts an object to json map.
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson();
}

and have your serializable classes implement that interface:
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

import 'serializable.dart';

part 'person.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Person implements Serializable{
  final String name;
  final int age;

  Person({required this.name, required this.age});

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => _$PersonFromJson(json);

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PersonToJson(this);
}

Your main function could then be something like:
import 'package:stackoverflow/stackoverflow.dart';

bool isSerializable<T>(T object) {
  return object is Serializable;
}

bool isSubType<S, T>() => <S>[] is List<T>;

bool isSerializableType<T>() => isSubType<T, Serializable>();

void processSerializable<T extends Serializable>(T object) {}

void main() {
  var person = Person(name: 'John', age: 30);

  // This should compile only if T is serializable
  // processSerializable(27); // Does not compile

  processSerializable(person); // OK

  print(person is Serializable); // True
  print(isSerializable(4)); // False !!!!
  print(isSerializable(person)); // True
  print(isSerializableType<Person>()); // True
}

The draw-back is that serializable objects like int, String, etc are not covered.
The function isSubType<S,T>() is from this stackoverflow answer.

abstract interface is double-talk;  interface class is a syntax error; and Serializabe is the name of an existing interface in the JDK. Three strikes and you’re out.

@user207421 In Dart 3.0,  the keyword interface is a class modifier, and is used in front of class.  The idiomatic way of defining a pure interface is abstract interface class, see: https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#abstract-interface .

very interesting approach @DanR . How would you deal with the fromJSON method? Would be great being able to check as well if given an objeto, it's possible to create instances from a JSON file
